# How to associate JSPlumb overlay with its connection?

Tags: jquery, graph, jsplumb

I am currently making a web-app graph editor. The user is expected to input a string on to each connection made in JsPlumb. Using an  custom overlay, I am able to let the user type in their string. I am able to retrieve the string, but I have no idea how to associate it with each edge. An example can be seen here in the JsFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/biocalc/t7uskkvm/1/

CODE:

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {    
var a = $("#a");
var b = $("#b");

var stateMachineConnector = {
    connector:"Bezier",
    paintStyle:{lineWidth:3,strokeStyle:"#056"},
    endpoint:"Blank",
    anchor:"Continuous",
    overlays:[[ "Arrow", { location: 0.7 } ], [ "Custom", { create:function(component) {
                return $("<input class='edgeInput' type='text' placeholder='input' style='color:black;background:none;text-align:center;border:none'>1</input>");}, location: 0.4}]]
};

   jsPlumb.connect({
        source:"a",
        target:"b"
    }, stateMachineConnector);


jsPlumb.draggable($(".window"));
jsPlumb.animate($("#b"), {"left": 50,"top": 300},{duration:"slow"});
jsPlumb.animate($("#a"), {"left": 250,"top": 100},{duration:"slow"});
});
```

My program allows users to create multiple edges, each with their own input box. I am not sure how to dynamically organize the data so that each edge corresponds to it's input box.

Comment: the fiddle gives `jsPlumb is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `component` parameter passed into the `create` function in your custom overlay is a reference to the underlying connection.  You can use that to do what you need to to associate edges with their input boxes, for example by storing the pairs in an array, as follows:

```
var connectionsToInputs = [];

var stateMachineConnector = {
connector:"Bezier",
paintStyle:{lineWidth:3,strokeStyle:"#056"},
endpoint:"Blank",
anchor:"Continuous",
overlays:[[ "Arrow", { location: 0.7 } ], [ "Custom", {  
    create:function(component) {
        var el = $("<input class='edgeInput' type='text' placeholder='input' style='color:black;background:none;text-align:center;border:none'>1</input>");
        connectionsToInputs.push([component, el]);
        return el;
    }, 
location: 0.4}]]
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem using a caching method.